Can I say "I have to take her/his call" instead of "I have to take this"?
This is what I often see in a film. A man's phone is ringing and the man says to his friend "I'm sorry I have to take this (call)". Then he presses the blue button to start talking on the phone.
So, instead of saying "I have to take this", can I say "I have to take his/ her call" (depending the gender of the one who called me)?

ChatGPT is right. "Mary called Tom and Tom took his call" is grammatical but it means something different to "Mary called Tom and Tom took her call". In English, the gender of "his/her" matches the gender of the person making the call, not the gender of the noun "call" - is that what's confusing you?

Let's not kid ourselves that chatgpt knows what it's talking about. The initial rephrasing Mary called someone else, and Tom answered the call on Mary's behalf is just nonsense. The statement Mary called Tom and Tom took her call means that Tom answered Mary's call (with the implication that he might have declined to answer). On that basis alone, I don't think there's any point in dissecting  anything else chatgpt has to say about such constructions.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking to explain some nonsense generated by chatgpt.

Besides which, context is everything. The final assertion above in the question is that Mary called Tom and Tom took his call is not valid, but that's incorrect. It simply requires the right context. Perhaps office support worker Tom had been refusing to take calls from customer Dick, but manager Mary called Tom on an internal line and ordered him to take Dick's call (which he did, because she's the boss).

@FumbleFingers, I don't understand what you are talking about. You made a decision so quickly without standing at the leaner's viewpoint. See my updated question, you will understand what I mean.

You're randomly jumping around changing the question. The current version seems unrelated to the original that cited "explanations" from chatgpt about the meaning of contrived sentences that wouldn't be spoken by native Anglophones. The answer to the current question is that it's nonsense to use his/her as a determiner before the referent has been contextually identified. Identified by something more "direct" than the inference that if the phone is ringing, there must be a person trying to get in contact.

I was flabbergasted to see FIVE downvotes while I was reviewing the question in the close votes queue. Then I looked at the edit history, some users instinctively downvote any post that even breathes the name ChatGPT, this is absurd behaviour. I suggest that Tom visits meta and ask if it is strictly forbidden to mention the chatbot as a reference or source. By the way, it isn't.

To take someone's call usually means "to not refuse to speak to a person who is calling you but to engage in conversation".
If you want to say something like "Account Rep Mary was out of the office so Account Rep Tom took a call that came in for Mary" you could say

A call came in for Mary, who was out of the office, so Tom took the call for her.
A call came in for Mary, who was out of the office, so Tom took the call.

The least likely yet not impossible variant would be:

A call came in for Mary, who was out of the office, so Tom took her call.

The explicitly stated context "who was out of the office" resolves the ambiguity. Absent that explicit context, or absent a general understanding on the part of the listener that Mary was out of the office and that Mary and Tom were colleagues, the statement could be puzzling.

I feel like either you don;t understand me or I misunderstand the phrase "take a call". This is what I often see in a film. A man's phone is ringing and the man says to his friend "I'm sorry I have to take this (call)".

@Tom  And I feel you don't pay enough attention to detail. I wrote take someone's call not take a call.

So that is the confusing point or the most important point. You need to clarify to learners like me. Why do people say "I have to take this" but not "I have to take her call" or "..his call" etc.

@Tom But  your question was based on the confusion of people involved in the call. That is what your question was about.

No, I am a learner. I got confused about "his call" or "this call". Why do people say "I have to take this" when their phone is ringing, but not "I have to take his/her call"

@Tom  People do say "I have to take his/her call".  The very first sentence in my answer  says that is indeed the usual way the phrase "take someone's call" is used.  And my question goes on to address your scenario where someone answers a call on behalf of a coworker.

A call is for someone from someone.

I updated my question so you had better update your answer or close it because your answer does not answer the question.

If you have to interrupt a face-to-face conversation to answer your phone, it usually doesn't matter to the other person whether the caller is male or female. "This call" is the one that is just coming through. If the call is particularly important because of who it's from, you might say "Sorry, it's my son - I have to take his call."

@Tom  Totally altering your question like that after someone has taken the time to answer your first one is discourteous.

and you said " take someone's call usually means "to not refuse to speak..." . This is the new thing.

If you don't "take the call" you do not engage in a conversation with the caller.  You can just let the phone ring, or let it go to voicemail, or tell a secretary or coworker to say you are not available, etc etc.  "I have to take this call" or "I have to take his/her call" is something you say, typically to someone with whom you are talking face-to-face or on the phone, when you need to apologize for interrupting your conversation in order to speak with the other person who is calling now.

But you would use the pronoun "his/her" normally only if your interlocutor knows (or has been told) who the person calling is:  "It's the Vice President on the line. I have to take her call." You'd say "this call" when you think your interlocutor has no need to know anything further about it.  This is common sense, not grammar.
